# Is there any way to view nfmark like ctmark?

Tags: iptables, netfilter, ip-conntrack

I understand that `iptables --set-mark` does not add mark "on" the packets. The `MARK` target is for associating a mark with the packet in the kernel data structures. The packet itself is not modified. But is there any way to view the packet with its associated mark?

We can see `ctmark` (connection marks which are set using `CONNMARK` target) from `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`. I am looking for something similar for viewing `nfmark` (packet marks).

This is how we can view `ctmark`.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -t mangle -m conntrack --ctorigdst 172.30.138.151 -m mark --mark 0 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Then we can see the connection mark in the `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` file. **mark=2**

```
ipv4     2 icmp     1 18 src=157.43.150.253 dst=172.30.138.151 type=8 code=0 id=54809 packets=4 bytes=336 src=172.30.138.151 dst=157.43.150.253 type=0 code=0 id=54809 packets=4 bytes=336 mark=2 zone=0 use=2
```

Another question about the `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` output. What is the meaning of the field `use`? I have seen `use=1`, `use=2` etc. [This website](http://www.dqd.com/~mayoff/notes/linux/ip_conntrack.html) says it is "Use count of this connection structure".

Comment: iptables' LOG target will write the packet's mark at the end of the log line if it's non zero.

Comment: @A.B Yes, you are right. Now, I can see the nfmarks. `kern.debug kernel: [11007.886926] IPTables-Marks: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=e4:xx:xx:xx:97:32:28:xx:xx:xx:fb:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.8.10 DST=192.168.8.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36764 DPT=22 WINDOW=254 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 MARK=0x2` Thank you. You can add your comment as a detailed answer, if you want.

Comment: turned it into a proper answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is about the *fwmark* or just *mark* (historically named *nfmark* but [renamed to just *mark*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/include/linux/skbuff.h?h=v2.6.20&id=82e91ffef60e6eba9848fe149ce1eecd2b5aef12) at the same time it didn't depend anymore on netfilter. The word *nfmark* is now a bit misleading, but still present in a few places which weren't or couldn't be updated). This mark is done on the packet's [*skbuff*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.29/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L829), while the *conntrack mark* (aka *ctmark* etc.) is done on a [conntrack entry](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.29/source/include/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.h#L93).

The easiest way to get a packet's mark is to log it via iptables' [`LOG`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#LOG) target. Something like this (with a limit to avoid flood):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mark ! --mark 0 -m limit --limit 8/min --limit-burst 12 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Marks: "
```

should log packets with a mark. The mark (when non-zero, which is the case with the match chosen above) is displayed at the end of the log line. (From OP's comment) example:

```
kern.debug kernel: [11007.886926] IPTables-Marks: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=e4:xx:xx:xx:97:32:28:xx:xx:xx:fb:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.8.10 DST=192.168.8.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=23698 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36764 DPT=22 WINDOW=254 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 MARK=0x2
```

There are other methods, better suited for automatization but harder to implement, like iptables' [`NFLOG`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#NFLOG) target intended to "send" the whole packet to a logging program listening on a netlink socket, which could retrieve the mark with [`nflog_get_nfmark()`](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_log/doxygen/html/group__Parsing.html#ga3977697e47a2ba7a1fac1fdb986484da) (old naming...). `tcpdump` can listen to the nflog facility (try `tcpdump --list-interfaces`) and display selected packets, which can sometimes be handier than logs to debug, but I don't know of a way to have it also display the mark (it doesn't know about `nflog_get_nfmark()` or how to ask libpcap about it).

Comment: Just looked around and did a few tests for `use=`. One way to get a value above 1 is when a conntrack protocol helper (eg: nf_conntrack_ftp) associated a related connection (for ftp that would be during data transfer): it keeps a reference on the master connection which increases the use count. Then when the related connection disappears completely (eg: after the TIME_WAIT state disappeared and the entry is destroyed), use will decrement again by one.